# Format existing date column to different format in R

Tags: r, date, format

I need to convert date column to a different format in R.

Data:

```
Year  Plant_Date
2010  May-08-2010
2010  Apr-09-2010
2010  June-02-2010
```

Output:

```
Year  Plant_Date
2010  05/08/2010
2010  04/09/2010
2010  06/02/2010
```

How to do this in R?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the documentation of `as.Date` function and then use `format` function on the date objects (e.g. %Y is 4-digit year, %d is the day, %b is abbreviated month). I assume "June" is "Jun", since the other months are abbreviated:

```
# the raw strings:
> (inString <- c("May-08-2010", "Apr-09-2010", "Jun-02-2010"))
[1] "May-08-2010" "Apr-09-2010" "Jun-02-2010"

# convert to date object:
> (inDates <- as.Date(inDates, format = "%b-%d-%Y"))
[1] "2010-05-08" "2010-04-09" "2010-06-02"

# format using format function:
> format(inDates, "%m/%d/%Y")
[1] "05/08/2010" "04/09/2010" "06/02/2010"
```